# Laravel get relations return wrong data

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database

I have four tables, `seller`, `products,` and `buyers`, `downloads`, the logic is: seller can make `products` and buyers can buy `products` and it store in `downloads` table. so for example:

**Seller:**

```
---------------------
|id | name | phone  |
---------------------
| 1 | mike | 989898 |
---------------------
| 2 | joe  | 989898 |
---------------------
```

**Products:**

```
---------------------
|id | name | user_id|
---------------------
| 1 | benz |    1   |
---------------------
| 2 | bmw  |    1   |
---------------------
```

**Buyers:**

```
----------------------
|id | name   | phone  |
----------------------
| 1 | carlos | 989898 |
----------------------
| 2 | nina   | 989898 |
----------------------
```

**Downloads:**

```
-----------------------------
|id | product_id  | buyer_id |
-----------------------------
| 1 |      1      |     2    |
-----------------------------
| 2 |      2      |     2    |
-----------------------------
```

So consider an buyer bought a product with `id` 2, I want to get products (id 2) and seller data (id 1), in other hand, `nina` bought `benz` and `bmw`, these products belongs to mike, so I want to get products data and seller data in buyerController.

```
class Buyer extends Authenticatable
{
...
    public function downloads(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Download','buyer_id');
    }

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product','App\Seller', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**In controller:**

```
public function files()
{
    $buyer = Buyer::find($id);
    $files = Buyer::with('downloads', 'products')->get();

    return $files;
}
```

It works without any error but return wrong data, for example a product that buyer not buy and also it not return seller data, it just return `"laravel_through_key": 1`. First function work good but second, `hasManyThrough` not working correctly.

I am new to Laravel, specially relations.
What I have done wrong?

Comment: $files = Buyer::with('downloads', 'products')->get();

Comment: Try this. its work

Comment: @VikasKatariya `Call to undefined relationship [downloads] on model [App\Seller]`

Comment: please put your controller code in detail

Comment: Is it `Buyer` or `Agent`?

Comment: @VikasKatariya buyerController?

Comment: yes please put .

Comment: @Styx oh, corrected, these are example names.

Comment: please select below answer. thank you happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your explanation, `Buyer` has direct relation `downloads` and indirect relation `products`, but latter is through `downloads`, not `sellers`. Thus, it should be:

```php
class Buyer extends Authenticatable
{
  //...
  public function downloads()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Download::class);
  }

  public function products()
  {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class, Download::class,
      'buyer_id', 'id', 'id', 'product_id');
  }
}
```

Don't forget to write relations for other models:

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    function seller()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Seller::class, 'user_id');
    }
    function downloads()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Download::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class Download extends Model
{
    function product()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    function buyer()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Buyer::class);
    }
}
```

Now you can use its power:

**1. Get buyer products:**

```
>>> App\Buyer::find(2)->products
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3018
     all: [
       App\Product {#3022
         id: 1,
         name: "benz",
         user_id: 1,
         laravel_through_key: 2,
       },
       App\Product {#3019
         id: 2,
         name: "bmw",
         user_id: 1,
         laravel_through_key: 2,
       },
     ],
   }
```

**2. The same but with seller info**

```
>>> App\Buyer::find(2)->products()->with('seller')->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3026
     all: [
       App\Product {#3034
         id: 1,
         name: "benz",
         user_id: 1,
         laravel_through_key: 2,
         seller: App\Seller {#3038
           id: 1,
           name: "mike",
           phone: "989898",
         },
       },
       App\Product {#3031
         id: 2,
         name: "bmw",
         user_id: 1,
         laravel_through_key: 2,
         seller: App\Seller {#3038},
       },
     ],
   }
```

Comment: Right but it should return two products not one, something is wrong and I debugging, because in my database, buyer has two downloads (products), but your code return one

Comment: @tourtravel Yes, sorry, there was an error. Fixed it and updated my answer.